# How to handle simultaneous running in migrate-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, migrate-mongo

I'm working on migration mechanism that should effect db changes between versions using npm package migrate-mongo. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate-mongo)
I've set the code to run on server init.
By the package documentation when I use the "up" command it recognizes pending migrations on the current db and run it.
The issue is that we have multiple instances of node and on deploy a migration can run more than once.

Here is the code I use to apply the migrations:

```
if (!some(res, {appliedAt: 'PENDING'})) {
    return;
}
const migratedFiles = await up(db);
```

**How to prevent simultaneous running?**

Comment: What of orchestration service do you use to deploy your node js service ?